# Showing ProgressBar while next activity loads

Tags: android

I have an activity called PasswordActivity.  Once the user inputs the correct password, the next activity is started using the startActivity method.  The next activity takes a while to launch because there are some tasks that must be performed before the UI is ready.  I don't want the user to think that the app froze at the PasswordActivity, so I want to add some kind of progress bar.  I would like to make the progress bar show actual progress of the next activity's loading progress, not just a spinning bar.  Can I do this in the PasswordActivity or in a splash screen loading activity between the activities, or is this not possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify where are the heavy-lifting processes happening at? The way I see it, once the input process has finished and user proceeds to next activity, the long tasks are performed in the other Activity. Is this correct?

Comment: @CatalinGhita Correct.  The onCreate method of the next activity contains a lot of time-consuming tasks, or so I assume since it takes a long time to load.  I have to query a local database for information to fill parts of the UI and whatnot.  All of the DB operations are not done on the main thread, so I am not sure why it takes so long, but it takes about 5 seconds to launch the next activity, so it looks like the UI is frozen while the next activity launches, and I would like to avoid that.  I thought of having an indeterminate progress bar, but I would prefer a determinate one if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              progressdialog.show();
                Intent in= new Intent(aa.this, 
                     bb.class);
                startActivity(in);
          progressdialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there a way to reflect the live status of the next (bb) activity's loading progress in the progressdialog in the example you provided?

Comment: progressdialog.setMessage("whatever you are goining on a next activity");

Answer (score 0):

depends on your nature of work you are doing
if using Asynctask

```
                 new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        mProgresDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LauncherActivity.this,"App Name","Loading...");
                        super.onPreExecute();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                        //To Do
                        return status;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String mStrStatus) {
                        super.onPostExecute(mStrStatus);
                        if(mProgresDialog != null && mProgresDialog.isShowing()){
                            mProgresDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }.execute("");
```